# My form won't work

Tags: php, html

This form works well in choosing a season and an episode with my php handling script:

```
<form action="view" method="get">
<font color="white">Season:</font><select name="s">
 <option id="s" value="1">1</option>
</select>
<font color="white">Episode: </font><select name="e">
 <option id="e" value="1">1</option>
 <option id="e" value="2">2</option>
 <option id="e" value="3">3</option>
 <option id="e" value="4">4</option>
 <option id="e" value="5">5</option>
 <option id="e" value="6">6</option>
 <option id="e" value="7">7</option>
 <option id="e" value="8">8</option>
 <option id="e" value="9">9</option>
 <option id="e" value="10">10</option>
 <option id="e" value="11">11</option>
 <option id="e" value="12">12</option>
 <option id="e" value="13">13</option>
 <option id="e" value="14">14</option>
 <option id="e" value="15">15</option>
 <option id="e" value="16">16</option>
 <option id="e" value="17">17</option>
 <option id="e" value="18">18</option>
 <option id="e" value="19">19</option>
 <option id="e" value="20">20</option>
 <option id="e" value="21">21</option>
 <option id="e" value="22">22</option>
 <option id="e" value="23">23</option>
 <option id="e" value="24">24</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

So, can anyone tell me why this form won't work to pick a random episode?

```
<form action="view" method="get">
<input type="hidden" id="s" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="e" value="<?php echo(rand(1,24)); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Watch Random Episode">
</form>
```

It won't append the variables to the end of the url, all I get is this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/media/show/view/?
```

Comment: Only elements with `name` are submitted with the form.

Comment: Though out of context, please don't use obsolete tags like ``font``.

Comment: @sarbbottam I only use the font tag when testing a code before it goes live. It's a fast way to see the outcome. Don't worry, I use css on my live site, not the font tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hidden inputs need a name attribute. In the same way that the select elements have a name..

```
<input type="hidden" name="s" id="s" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="e" id="e" value="<?php echo(rand(1,24)); ?>">
```

Comment: Lol, oops... Yeah, I knew that once upon a time. Thanks a lot gratz.

Comment: i think need space to echo values? any syntax error?

Comment: @RakeshSharma No syntax errors, just forgot a simple html attribute lol

Comment: @Davie that's good, don't  forgot to accept/upvote helpful answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
<?php  
$ep = rand(1,24);
echo $ep;
?>
<form action="view" method="get">
<input type="hidden" id="s" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="e" name="e" value="<?php echo $ep; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Watch Random Episode">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define **name** attribute to each field and one space to `echo and print value`

```
<input type="hidden" id="s" value="1" name ="s">
<input type="hidden" id="e" name = "e" value="<?php echo rand(1,24); ?>">
```

Second check you have htaccess `[QSA]` also with rules